# Fichero PHP como inclur un archivo sin que dé error

Tags: php, linux, php7, php5, php-5.6

Tengo un script en PHP que usa el SDK de google y para ello necesito el fichero "credentials.json" con lo que la estructura del proyecto queda de esta forma

/file.php

/config/credentials.json

El problema lo tengo al ejecutar el archivo file.php me dice que no puede acceder al archivo credentials.json si llamo el script desde fuera de la carpeta es decir, el proyecto esta en /var/www/html/test/file.php y yo hago la llamada desde un crontab con la URL entera "php /var/www/html/test/file.php parametro" pasandole un parametro me da este error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: file "credentials.json" does not
          exist in /var/www/html/test/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php:980
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/test/config/functions.php(356): Google\Client->setAuthConfig('credentials.jso...')
#1 /var/www/html/test/file.php(147): traducciones(Object(mysqli))
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/test/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php on line 980
```

En cambio si me posiciono en el directorio /var/www/html/test/ con un "cd /var/www/html/test/" y ejecuto "php file.php parametro" no me da este error.

A que es debido y como puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias

Comment: No le pongas todas la ruta /var/www/html/test/....   si no ponle /test i ja esta.
El apache de linux te esta leyendo directamente /var/www/html ese es tu localhost y todo lo que pongas alli sera la web. Tienes que pensar en url absoluta lo que como deberia de leerlo el navegador y seria a partir de la carpeta test

Comment: @JordiTurell: Diria que lo quiere ejecutar con el cron, es decir, no con apache sino desde el sistema de archivos tal cual

Comment: Exacto lo quiero llamar desde un cron.

Comment: podes usar [`realpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php) : `echo realpath( './config.json');` o usando la constante `__DIR__` : `echo  __DIR__ . "/config.json";` o una combinación `echo realpath( __DIR__ . "/../logs/debug.log" );` <- este ultimo va bien para cli, cron, fpm y mod_php cuando hay q subir un nivel

Answer (score 1):

PHP (en mi experiencia) puede ser un poco tricky con estos temas. Una forma de evitarlo es que coloques un archivo de config en el directorio raíz del proyecto donde puedas indicar en una variable la ruta **en el FS** al proyecto.

Por ejemplo, podría ser algo como esto:

`config.php`. Contenido:

```
$FS_ROOT="/var/www/html/blahblah";
```

En un script que está en un subdirectorio, haces el include del archivo config con rutas relativas:

```
require_once("../config.php");
```

y a partir de ahí puedes indicar rutas a cualquier otro archivo del proyecto usando `$FS_ROOT`:

```
require_once("$FS_ROOT/unsubdir/blahblah.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto al principio de `file.php` para que haga el `cd` y colocarte en el directorio donde si funciona:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```